# Can I lose my EU driving license in Germany?

Tags: germany, driving-license

I'm living in Germany and I have a Bulgarian driving license. Can I get the so called *Points in Flensburg* for driving offences if I don't have a German driving license?

Comment: I would guess that you might be forced to get a German license first.

Comment: No, that entity in Flensburg does not manage driving licenses, it manages traffic offenses regardless of place of residence of the driver.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First up: I am not a lawyer. But verifiable sources confirm you can get points like a German, even when you're holding a foreign driver's license.

For example, here's a quote from [the website of the German city of Hamm](http://www.hamm.de/rathaus/buergerservice/anliegen-von-a-z/civserv.html?tx_civserv_pi1%5Bcommunity_id%5D=1110000&tx_civserv_pi1%5Bmode%5D=service&tx_civserv_pi1%5Bid%5D=188&cHash=ce70f1848d20cf16a42c12869b3f4bad) (section II, 3rd paragraph) related to holding a driver's license issued by EU countries while living in Germany:

> Läuft Ihre Fahrerlaubnis nach den deutschen Vorschriften eher ab als in Ihrem Heimatstadt, wird die neue Geltungsdauer bei der Registrierung in Ihren Führerschein eingetragen. Ist ein solcher Eintrag wegen der Beschaffenheit des Führerscheins nicht möglich, erhalten Sie einen entsprechenden deutschen Führerschein.
>
> Ein Verstoß gegen die Pflicht zur Registrierung wird mit einem Bußgeld geahndet und **führt zu Punkten im Verkehrszentralregister**.

<sup>(emphasis mine)</sup>

Translating that into English using my own words, they state that…

If, under German law, your license expires earlier than in your hometown, the new period of validity will be noted in your driver's license at the
license register. If it's not possible to add such an entry due to the nature of the license, you will receive a German driver's license. A breach of this obligation to register is punishable by a fine and **leads to points at the Verkehrszentralregister (also known as the “Kraftfahrtbundesamt”) in Flensburg**.

So, Yes – if you live in Germany and hold a Bulgarian (EU country) driving license, you can very well get (so called) 'Points in Flensburg' as described in [Straßenverkehrsgesetz – § 4](http://www.gesetze-im-internet.de/stvg/__4.html) (Road Traffic Act). If you accumulate enough of those points, German law states that your driver's license can be “put on hold” or, depending on the violation(s) and total points on your record, even completely revoked!

Also, there are some additional restrictions and things to watch out for when holding a foreign driver's license, which may also apply to you. But I assume you're already aware of those. If you aren't, you should contact your local authorities to learn where to get that information.

In case of doubt, the [Straßenverkehrsgesetz](http://www.gesetze-im-internet.de/bundesrecht/stvg/gesamt.pdf) (PDF of complete Road Traffic Act) is a solid resource!

Answer (score 8):

Yes. Actually, if the "[Verkehrszentralregister](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Verkehrszentralregister)" (the formal name of that well-known entity in Flensburg) issues an order to prohibit you from driving on German roads once you have reached a threshold of points, they might even inform your country of residence to collect your driving license and place a note there that you are prohibited from driving in Germany for a period.

Comment: They take it actually from you. Some people have asked for duplicates in their origin country pretending they've lost the driving licence, but they were punished for false testimony because of information exchange withing EU.